# Autoplay video when modal opens html

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, modal-dialog, simplemodal

i'm new to html and web development, I am testing a basic page where a button opens a modal and in that modal there's a video.

Can you help me making it autoplay when the modal opens and stop when it closes? I tried a lot op options i found on the web but I can´t get it to work.

I started using w3schools examples.

```
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Work+Sans&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<style>
body, button {font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif;}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 7px; /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
  -webkit-animation-name: animatetop;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
  animation-name: animatetop;
  animation-duration: 0.4s
}

/* Add Animation */
@-webkit-keyframes animatetop {
  from {top:-300px; opacity:0} 
  to {top:0; opacity:1}
}

@keyframes animatetop {
  from {top:-300px; opacity:0}
  to {top:0; opacity:1}
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
  color: black;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.modal-header {
  padding: 2px 16px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: white;
  color: white;
}

.modal-body {padding: 2px 16px;}

.modal-footer {
  padding: 2px 16px;
  background-color: #004F9E;
  color: white;
}

div.parent {
    text-align: center;
    }
ul { 
    display: inline-block; 
    text-align: left; 
    }
    
button {
        background-color: #004F9E; /* Green */
        border: 2px solid #004F9E;
        border-radius: 5px;
        color: white;
        padding: 5px 10px;
        text-align: center;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 14px;
        }
        
button {
        transition-duration: 0.4s;
        }

button:hover {
  background-color: white; 
  color: black; 
  border: 2px solid #004F9E;
}



myBtn {
        display: flex; 
        justify-content: center; 
        border: none;
        }
    
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2 style='text-align:center'>Titulo</h2>

<div class="parent">
    <ul>
  <li>order1.</li>

  <li>order2.</li>

  <li>orde3.</li>

    
</ul>
</div>

<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<div class="parent">
    <button id="myBtn">Ver Video</button>
</div>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-body">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
     <div  style='text-align:center'>
        <video width="100%"; height="95%" controls>
        <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        Your browser does not support the video tag.
        </video>
        </div>
    </div>
    
     
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<script>
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block"
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
  
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}

  
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `play()` and `pause()`

```
document.getElementById('myVideo').play(); // <-- PLAY
```

```
document.getElementById('myVideo').pause(); // <-- PAUSE
```

In the example, I have commented on the places where I added these new lines

**Example:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Work+Sans&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <style>
        body,
        button {
            font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif;
        }

        /* The Modal (background) */
        .modal {
            display: none;
            /* Hidden by default */
            position: fixed;
            /* Stay in place */
            z-index: 1;
            /* Sit on top */
            padding-top: 7px;
            /* Location of the box */
            left: 0;
            top: 0;
            width: 100%;
            /* Full width */
            height: 100%;
            /* Full height */
            overflow: auto;
            /* Enable scroll if needed */
            background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
            /* Fallback color */
            background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
            /* Black w/ opacity */
        }

        /* Modal Content */
        .modal-content {
            position: relative;
            background-color: #fefefe;
            margin: auto;
            padding: 0;
            border: 1px solid #888;
            width: 80%;
            box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
            -webkit-animation-name: animatetop;
            -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
            animation-name: animatetop;
            animation-duration: 0.4s
        }

        /* Add Animation */
        @-webkit-keyframes animatetop {
            from {
                top: -300px;
                opacity: 0
            }

            to {
                top: 0;
                opacity: 1
            }
        }

        @keyframes animatetop {
            from {
                top: -300px;
                opacity: 0
            }

            to {
                top: 0;
                opacity: 1
            }
        }

        /* The Close Button */
        .close {
            color: black;
            float: right;
            font-size: 28px;
            font-weight: bold;
        }

        .close:hover,
        .close:focus {
            color: #000;
            text-decoration: none;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        .modal-header {
            padding: 2px 16px;
            height: 30px;
            background-color: white;
            color: white;
        }

        .modal-body {
            padding: 2px 16px;
        }

        .modal-footer {
            padding: 2px 16px;
            background-color: #004F9E;
            color: white;
        }

        div.parent {
            text-align: center;
        }

        ul {
            display: inline-block;
            text-align: left;
        }

        button {
            background-color: #004F9E;
            /* Green */
            border: 2px solid #004F9E;
            border-radius: 5px;
            color: white;
            padding: 5px 10px;
            text-align: center;
            text-decoration: none;
            display: inline-block;
            font-size: 14px;
        }

        button {
            transition-duration: 0.4s;
        }

        button:hover {
            background-color: white;
            color: black;
            border: 2px solid #004F9E;
        }

        /* #myBtn {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            border: none;
        } */
    </style>

</head>
<body>

    <h2 style='text-align:center'>Titulo</h2>

    <div class="parent">
        <ul>
            <li>order1.</li>

            <li>order2.</li>

            <li>orde3.</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
    <div class="parent">
        <button id="myBtn">Ver Video</button>
    </div>

    <!-- The Modal -->
    <div id="myModal" class="modal">

        <!-- Modal content -->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <span class="close">&times;</span>
                <div style='text-align:center'>
                    <video id="myVideo" width="100%" height="95%" controls>
                        <source src="https://www.learningcontainer.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/sample-mp4-file.mp4"
                            type="video/mp4">
                        Your browser does not support the video tag.
                    </video>
                </div>
            </div>


        </div>
    </div>

    </div>

    <script>
        // Get the modal
        var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

        // Get the button that opens the modal
        var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

        // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
        var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

        // When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
        btn.onclick = function () {
            modal.style.display = "block"
            document.getElementById('myVideo').play(); // <-- PLAY
        }

        // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
        span.onclick = function () {
            modal.style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('myVideo').pause(); // <-- PAUSE
        }

        // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
        window.onclick = function (event) {
            if (event.target == modal) {
                modal.style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById('myVideo').pause(); // <-- PAUSE
            }
        }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```